# About Tail recursive optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, recursion, tail

I used the below two functions to test the Tail recursive optimization under MSVC08

```
int TailRecursively1(int i)
{
  return TailRecursively1(i);
}

int TailRecursively2(std::string str)
{
  return TailRecursively2(str);
}
```

why has TailRecursively1 been optimized, but TailRecursively2 has caused the stack overflow?

Comment: The second one is not tail recursive. There is a destructor call after the recursion.

Comment: @lego: looks likely, and easy to check too, what of `TailRecursively3(std::string&)` (note the `&`) ?

Comment: If string is passed in by reference then `int TailRec(std::string& s) { return TailRec(s); }` is tail recursive - there are no operations left to be performed after recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Because there are calls for std::string copy constructor and destructor when sending the str parameter by value to TailReucrsively2?

(I'm not 100% sure about this)